# Debugging USB Device Driver. Interpreting USB Analyzer logs

Tags: usb, driver, device-driver

EE here. I was tasked with building a USB Hub onto one of our boards, and I chose the TI part TUSB2077A. Everything seems to work properly except when I disconnet one of our devices, but it doesn't happen all the time; I can safely say that it happens about 5% of the disconnections.

My initial assumption was that it had to do with improper layout, ESD, surge or any other electrical problem you can think up. I got all my toys out and started measuring, scoping, cutting traces, adding components, removing components, but no matter how much I did, I would always be able to duplicate the problem with the same frequency of occurrence.

I decided to sniff around the USB traffic and see what I could find, but device drivers are completely out of my expertise and I am unable to interpret the logs. I have been googling around many of the things I see, and they differences in the two logs are more than obvious, but I am still unable to determine if this is a faulty device driver, a faulty Windows usbhub.sys driver, or an error within the TI chip itself. Out of all the possibilities, I believe the fault device driver is the more likely, but before I contact my device provider, I wanted to understand better what is going on.

Can any USB expert out there take a look at these logs and tell me what you can interpret from them? I captured the full USB stack, so there are a lot of Bulk transfer messages, but if you scroll down about 1.8 seconds in you will see the magic happen.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/epdhsf9lcox5ci7/Full%20Stack%20Logs.zip

The problem:
When unpluggin the device from the Hub, the hub will reset and re-enumerate itself and therefor the devices attached to it. I have checked the reset line in the hub and it is not asserted, nor is VCC dropped by any level that would cause an electrical malfunction.

I have also checked for ESD, Surge, over current, over voltage and undervoltage problems and have found nothing. I have protection devices on my board, as well as EMI filters for the data pairs. All other devices work normally, and if I do not unplug the device, all my software tools, and our commercial software operates without faults. It is only when you unplug (about 5% of the unplugs) that we get this fault.

I can see from the logs that the "Host" is sending the "RESET_PORT" command/call (or whatever is called) after it tried to SYNC_RESET_PIPE_AND_CLEAR_STALL with unseccesful results. I notice from the logs that this call is not made on the OK log, and simply calls for a device removal. The RESET_PORT call is issues on the HUB, which makes me think that the issues arises on the device driver.

The HUB IC is a standard TI part, and is already in mass production. My schematic follows their guidelines and our board layout was made by a design house in South California well aware of the critical importance of good practice for USB design.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Gustavo, Did you ever find any explanation for this? I have been banging my head against the desk for a few days now with the exact same problem when running hub on full speed. We use a different hub chip, USB2513B. No issue when running the hub in high speed.

Comment: nuro, for us it turned out to be a very outdated driver. The company that made the device wanted $10K to give us a recent version of the driver. That's preposterous. At the same time, I notice that a microchip part didn't have this behaviour (USB2517), so I redesigned my hub and this issue went away.